# Windows 8.1 unable to delete nonexisting homegroup

Tags: windows-8, homegroup

On Windows 8.1 64bit, I am unable to delete non-existing HomeGroup that appears in ControlPanel->HomeGroup, at the same time I am unable to join the same non-existing HomeGroup, what is logical. When asked for pass for joining group windows returns that group does not exists (what is expected).

I tried deleting files from `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Roaming\PeerNetworking\`, and stopping HomeGroupProvider service. But files reappears again.

Also I tried all regular tips and tutorials from Microsoft web and similar sites. I removed all 2nd party antivirus and only WindowsDefender is remained.

Is there any solution for this issue?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same problem and here is the solution that works for me.
Working on **Windows 10**

### WHAT HAPPEND TO ME

I had a homegroup with 3 of my computers connected. Someday I wanted to delete it to get a new fresh one, I went on all my 3 computers and leave the homegroup (the normal way to do that).

After that all of my computer should have to ask me to create a new homegroup, **instead they all wanted to join a homegroup (a homegroup that wasn't exist anymore).**

I believe Windows forgot to delete some files on the "leaving homegroup" process, and my computers wanted to share a homegroup that they were no longer part of.

### SOLUTION

Shut down all your computers, boot a computer and apply these changes before boot another.

1. Open Task Manager > Services and stop **HomeGroupListener** and **HomeGroupProvider** services
2. Delete the content of `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Roaming\PeerNetworking\`
3. delete the contents of `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys` (Use [Unlocker](http://www.clubic.com/telecharger-fiche20237-unlocker.html) if needed to delete the folder, recreate it and set the full autorisations to everyone. Right Clic on the folder > Properties > Security)
4. open **regedit** (Windows > search > regedit  or Windows+R > regedit)
5. navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HomeGroupProvider\`
6. delete the contents of **ServiceData** and **LocalUserMembership**
7. navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HomeGroupListener\`
8. delete the contents of **ServiceData**
9. reboot
10. run homegroup troubleshooter a couple of times. (Windows search > Troubleshooter > Network & Internet > Homegroup)

**After that, all should be OK.**

I don't fully understand all of this changes, I applied answers I found on the web to this problem. Maybe there are steps that may not be required.

**NOTE particular to my case**

The third computer I wanted to reconnect to my Homegroup was wired via ethernet but not directly to my internet box. (I use 2 little devices to pass my internet signal from my box to my computer, through the electric system of my flat -> Idk the name).

And these boxes was also blocking the connection to the Homegroup, I had to connect this third computer by Wifi to my network to finally get my third computer connected to the Homegroup.

Answer (score 0):

try to run `services.msc` then stop the following services:
`peer networking grouping`
`peer networking identity manager`
then delete everything from here `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Roaming\PeerNetworking\`

waiting for you reply

Comment: this does not help. all the same.

Comment: try this may help [link](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15850-homegroup-leave-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: Helped the procedure with deleting  `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Roaming\PeerNetworking\` directory, on one another computer in network that was previously hosted HomeGroup on same network. Although, this computer that was previously hosted homegroup, has deleted all groups, and on them there was only option to create now one. But I wanted my first mentioned computer to be host.